# `Unsafe redirect to "https://${ip}/signin"` while running rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, security

I'm trying to analyze log from my rails applications I sometimes see hits from random IP addresses that look like this:

```
-------------------------------
Request:
-------------------------------

  * URL        : https://${ip}/
  * HTTP Method: GET
  * IP address : 162.62.191.231
  * Parameters : {"controller"=>"runner", "action"=>"index"}
  * Timestamp  : 2022-08-17 18:28:07 +0300
  * Server : b82b789929df
  * Rails root : /root/my_app
  * Process: 270
```

Those are not some replacement to hide IP from you, it seems like literally request with `https://${ip}/` value

But not sure from where it's coming, probably some guys are testing my site for some vulnerability, but I cannot detect which.
`https://${ip}/` is a really bad string to google it

And especially I cannot understand how to simulate the same request with `curl` or `wget` to see if it really safe

Answer (score 0):

Fact is that it couldn't get to your server unless it was a correct hostname/ip-address, so that URL is not what's being requested.  My guess here is that this is some local monitoring or health-check, is this on AWS?

Comment: It's on DigitalOcean, but I don't think I setup any monitoring software

It's not what I'm sure that **someone get into my server**, more like I want to trigger same message in logs by some request done by me and check that was it

Comment: Right, I just meant that the whole `https://${ip}/` thing is not really any part of the request, eg. that might just be an error in the logging setup.  According to the params, t's just the index action of your runner controller.

Comment: I agree that this can be an error in logger setup. Andy idea how I can trigger the same error to debug this situation?

Comment: Have you tried just hitting the index action of your runner controller?

Comment: Yeah seems there is some problem with `runner/index`, not sure if this is the same error as I've originally mentioned, but definitely something not right.

I'll fix it and see if any errors like in the original post will happen again, thank you